# Renaming SharePoint files in bulk by changing the date format on Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

the current file names are:

> DD- MM- YY Title of Document

I would like to change it to:

> YYYY-MM-DD Title of Document

For example: the title of the document is `28- 02- 2022 John Smith is ready for service`

And I would like to change the file name to `2022-02-28 John Smith is ready for service`

Comment: Ok so have you tried anything? Can you tell us the specific problem with what you’re wanting to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following power automate:

[image]

1.This step is to get bulk files contents.

[image]

2.The five compose is to extract string from the file name, at last I will reorganize the order for them.

The expressions from Compose2-Compose5 are:

```
substring(outputs('Compose'),10,add(length(outputs('Compose')),-10))
substring(outputs('Compose'),0,2)
substring(outputs('Compose'),6,4)
substring(outputs('Compose'),2,4)
```

[image]

3.Then we could create new files using the same file content, as we could not rename files in Power Automate, we need to create another file first and delete the previous files.

**Note: The outputs in the screenshot from left to right are Compose 4, 5, 3, 2.**

4.As you could see in the screenshot, the format has been changed. So the last step is to delete the previous files.

[image]